# c# need to get records >= today LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get dates that are greater than or equal to today.
I am using c# LINQ.

Just wondering if the following is the most efficient way of going about doing it:

```
pr.PgDate >= DateTime.Today
```

Comment: What problem have you had with this approach?

Comment: I would like to see some answers. Curious!

Comment: Are you using Linq to Object, Linq to SQL, or some ORM?  If you're using a database, what does the underlying table look like?  Lots of rows in said table? What indexes are on the underlying table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends,  assuming you are using a linq provider that turns this straight into SQL,  then it really comes down to the database.   Namely, do you have an index on the column which PgDate comes from?  if so, that's about the most efficient you will get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you're using an ORM this should translate directly to SQL (or other) and will execute in milliseconds on the db server.